# Cannot Enable/Disable Button(Script) Component of UI Button in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I want access to a component of a UI Button and want to enable a  disabled component "
**Button(Script)**" for unlocking the next level but it is not enable the component.

```
if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level") == 1){
   Button Level2 = Unlock.GetComponent<Button>();
   Level2.enabled = true;
}
```

P.S: No Syntax Error in my code.

Comment: Debug the code then edit your question with the result. It's hard to help you without that. Check if `Level2` is null  by putting `Debug.Log(Level2)` inside that if statement.. This will also tell you if that `if` that statement is even running.

Comment: You can also try to set the interacrable attribute from a button to false or true.

Comment: Thank you @cjf93 your comment save my time..

Comment: i posted as answer, maybe it works for someone else

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the interactable property of a Button to true o false.

```
Button myButton;
myButton.interactable = true;
//Here your button works normal

myButton.interactable = false;
//The click on your button is disabled here
```

Comment: Thanks I have already solved the problem with same method you have mentioned

Comment: I will add some thing for others that you should not disable whole component but use the variable of the component which act as whole component enable/disable option.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the if block is executed , make sure your "Unlock" -gameobject I guess- has a button component on it.
No syntax error doesn't mean you don't have conceptual error.